# session -- how to replace session_register & session_unregister PHP 5.2.9

Tags: php, session

please, I need your help. my hosting provider recently **changed the version of php** (according to phpinfo.php it's 5.2.9 and register_globals is off). and from this moment, i have problems with **logging into my website** (only password is insterted). please, can anyone advise me? thank you very much!

**file name: log.php**

```
<?  include('./config.php') ?>
<?  
    IF($co=="off"):
        Session_unregister("PASSWORD");
        UnSet($PASSWORD);
        Die();
    ENDIF;


    IF($password_form==$INI_ADMIN_PASSWORD):

        Session_register("PASSWORD");
        $PASSWORD = $password_form;

        Header("Location: status.php?login=true");
    ENDIF;

?>
```

**in file config.php, there is:**

```
<?
    Session_start();        

    $INI_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "********";


?>
```

and **password is interted in a form** (the excerpt):

```
<INPUT TYPE="password" SIZE="50" NAME="password_form"></INPUT>
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: PHP 5.2 has been [***END OF LIFE FOR ALMOST 5 YEARS***](http://php.net/eol.php) and they just *upgraded* to it?! FFS, *5.4* has been EOL for 2 months and PHP7 is about to release. Get off that host!

Answer (score 0):

To replace: `Session_unregister("PASSWORD");`

Use `unset($_SESSION["PASSWORD"]);`

And to replace: `Session_register("PASSWORD");`

Use `$_SESSION["PASSWORD"] = $PASSWORD;`

`session_start()` have to be kept the way it is.

However, if you used to use `register_globals` before, probably much more code is broken, and it's impossible to help you in a simple way, the code will need an extensive review.

Comment: thank you very much for your help... unfortunately, it still doesn't work... do you think, that this lines are o.k.?

`IF($password_form==$INI_ADMIN_PASSWORD):`
     `$_SESSION["PASSWORD"] = $PASSWORD;`
     `$PASSWORD = $password_form;`